# Which package should I install to solve this problem?

Tags: 14.04, package-management

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (32bits)

When I installed TORCS-1.3.1 (which is a sort of Racing game), Error is occurred.

Error is " No rule to make target `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/predefs.h', needed by`controlconfig.o'.  Stop."

Someone told me install libc6-dev, but it doesn't work.

Please help me

Thank you for reading it.

Comment: I just checked - this program is available in the Ubuntu repositories - so spare yourself some trouble and just install it through there: `sudo apt-get install torcs`

Answer (score 0):

Use `apt-file` to search through the contents of packages.

To install and build the file index:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

To search:

```
apt-file search predefs.h
```

That will give you a package name and an absolute path to where the file would be installed.

If that doesn't return anything, then search through [the Ubuntu package directory](http://packages.ubuntu.com) using the package contents search (make sure you have your version selected in the "Distribution" field).

If that didn't turn up anything, my last piece of advice would be to Google it (I.e. "Ubuntu trusty predefs.h package) - although, I should warn you, what you find may not be as secure as the other two methods.